# Rake error 'cannot load such file -- v8' when pushing to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, rake, shopify

Since adding shopify_app gem and generating the files from it on my Rails 4 project, I cannot push the changes to Heroku.

The app seems to run fine locally.

**Terminal output snippet...**

```
.
.
.
I, [2014-02-19T18:22:21.534285 #633]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_7560eb7a-eac1-486b-92a8-81484f0223bb/public/assets/shopify-1336e1537a57a0c4469a113563298c80.png
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- v8
(in /tmp/build_7560eb7a-eac1-486b-92a8-81484f0223bb/app/assets/stylesheets/imports.css.less)
/tmp/build_7560eb7a-eac1-486b-92a8-81484f0223bb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
.
.
.
```

**imports.css.less**

```
/*
 * Temporary fix until less-rails-bootstrap fixes issue #26 https://github.com/metaskills/less-rails-bootstrap/issues/26
 */

 @import "twitter/bootstrap/responsive";
```

I have tried adding the bootstrap file being requested into `app/assets/stylesheets/twitter/bootstrap/responsive.less` and also tried commenting out the line in question - each time making a commit before pushing to Heroku.

I have had this problem in the past and added `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false` to the Application class of `application.rb`, but this time that does not help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have managed to fix it by adding this to the Application class of `config/application.rb` like I had tried before...

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false`
```

**but** this time also adding this to `config/environment/production.rb`...

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

It means that I have to run this each time I have changed the assets and want to push the commit to Heroku....

```
rake assets:precompile
```

---

All this to prevent the Heroku precompile error, as it tries to initialise and attach to the DB before the ENV vars are available.

[[source](http://zirosas.wordpress.com/2013/06/02/twitter-bootstrap-for-rails/)]